# Can't insert newlines

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
<?php 
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

echo $ip;
echo "\n";
echo strftime('%c');
echo "\n";
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo "\n";
?>
```

All three outputs should be on three separate lines, but they are all on same. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browser interprets the output as html by default. If you want "see" the real output add this at the begin of file.

```
header("Content-type: text/plain");
```

or use a `<br />` instead of simple new line

Answer (score 3):

If you want to see output on newlines in the browser use the html line break `<br>` instead of `\n`. Browsers collapse white spaces (`\n` is a white space) into a single `' '`.

Answer (score 1):

Just add [The pre tag - Pre-formatted text](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp) `<pre>`

```
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

echo "<pre>";
echo $ip;
echo "\n";
echo strftime('%c');
echo "\n";
echo date_default_timezone_get();
echo "\n";
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

php-output in the browser is formatted as Html. In Html you need the tag <br> to start a new line ... :-)

```
echo "<br>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're viewing the page as HTML, then everything would be on one line. You need to add line breaks.

```
echo $ip . "<br />\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on viewing the output in HTML, you need to use HTML *line-breaks*.

```
<?php 
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];

echo $ip."<br>";
echo strftime('%c')."<br>";
echo date_default_timezone_get()."<br>";
?>
```